# При компиляции, данный участок кода зависает. GUI Java

Tags: java, swing, gui, jtextfield

Это часть основного кода. При компиляции ошибок нет, но после того как ввожу числа от 0 до 9 и нажимаю Continue. Кнопка залипает и не отпускается + интерфейс должен пропасть, но не пропадает. Никакого вывода нет.

```
     class alkashSP extends JFrame {
            JTextField jta = new JTextField(10);
            Font fnt = new Font("Times new roman", Font.BOLD, 25);

            alkashSP() {
                super("Input your cards. Like 2 5 6...");
                setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                setSize(300, 125);
                add(jta);
                jta.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                jta.setFont(fnt);
                JButton contButton = new JButton("Continue");
                contButton.setBounds(10, 40, 0, 10);
                add(contButton);
                jta.getText();
                contButton.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

                        var sp = new Stack<Integer>();
                        var reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                        String input = null;
                        try {
                            input = reader.readLine();
                        } catch (IOException ioException) {
                            ioException.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        var split = input.split(" ");
                        for (var t : split)
                        {
                            sp.push(Integer.parseInt(t));
                        }


                    }
                    @Override
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { }
                    @Override
                    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { }
                    @Override
                    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { }
                    @Override
                    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { }
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: А зачем вы считываете числа из консоли, если у вас для этого есть специальное поле для ввода?

Comment: @Dareten так метод getText() получает текст с JTextField

Comment: Он-то получает, но он никак не связан со стандартным потоком ввода из которого вы пытаетесь считать эту строку.

Comment: @Dareten как я могу её считать правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш нынешний код проще переписать примерно вот так:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Stack;

class Main extends JFrame {
    JTextField jta = new JTextField(10);
    Font fnt = new Font("Times new roman", Font.BOLD, 25);
    Stack<Integer> sp = new Stack<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         JFrame frame = new Main();
         frame.pack();
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
         frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    Main() {
        super("Input your cards. Like 2 5 6...");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(300, 125);
        add(jta);
        jta.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        jta.setFont(fnt);
        JButton contButton = new JButton("Continue");
        contButton.setBounds(10, 40, 0, 10);
        add(contButton);
        contButton.addActionListener(ae -> {
            String[] cards = jta.getText().split(" ");
            for (String card : cards) {
                sp.push(Integer.parseInt(card));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

На кнопку навешивается обычный ActionListener, потому что остальное излишне.
Массив строк считывается из поля ввода. Тут надо еще добавить проверку на наличие всех 10 цифр в массиве и делить карты между двумя игроками.